# Runtime error while compiling

Tags: c, gcc, runtime-error, turbo-c

Why do i get runtime eror when running this code in gcc compiler?? It works fine in turboC. I have been working on this for couple of days with no progress at all. Kindly help.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int T,i=0,num,sum,temp,j;
int *N;
scanf("%d",&T);
while(i++<T)
{
scanf("%d",N);
temp=*N;
while((*N)-->0)
{

    sum=0;
    num=(*N)+1;
    for(j=0;j<64;j++)
    {
    if(num&1)
        sum+=1;
    num=num>>1;
    }
if(((*N)+1+sum)==temp)
    break;
}
printf("%d\n",((*N)<0)?-1:(*N)+1);

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What line is the error on?  Did you run it in the debugger to find out?  One thing that is surely a problem is that `N` is a pointer that is not initialized to point to anything.  Why isn't it just an int?

Comment: Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your program got some.

Comment: If you compiled your program with warnings enabled you would have some hints,

Comment: So take the habit of always compiling with `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: BTW your title is wrong: the runtime error is not in `gcc` it is inside *your* program

Comment: The title was wrongly phrased. sorry. It actually didnt show any error. only that it gave diffent outputs when i use an int type of same value in place of the pointer in some places.

Comment: So how about you fix your title then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include the header file

```
# include <stdlib.h>
```

Allocate memory to the pointer before using it.

```
int *N;
N = (int *)malloc (sizeof (int));
```

Free the allocated memory after using it

```
free (N);
```

Comment: Better to not use a pointer at all.  I don't see any reason it is necessary in this code.

Comment: Since he is using it maybe its required for him, let him use but in a correct way.

Comment: i used pointers to reduce time of execution below 1 second. i couldnt do it with int.

Comment: Ok it's fine @Manu Mathew, just allocate memory it should work.

Comment: @ManuMathew That makes no sense at all unless this is not the actual code you're using.

Comment: Actually @Manu Mathew dynamic memory allocation will take more time than statically allocating memory. In this case if you don't use pointer it would be faster.

Comment: it was a problem in hackerearth. the time reduced from 1.0015s to .1342 s after using pointer. I am just a beginner. so i dont know why. Thank you for the reply.:) I will try this.

Comment: @ManuMathew using pointer won't save you time but cost you more for allocating on heap and pointer dereference. Use automatic variables on stack instead, just `int N` is enough

Comment: @Adarsh if you use pointer, remember to delete if after using, and [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Thank you all. I got the pointer part working correctly. As you all said the time remained kind of the same only. So the problem is still unsolved but learned a lot from this. Thank you